# Unknown variable 'dlv adName' found in a tag. Edit the tag and remove the reference to the unknown variable

Tags: google-tag-manager

Our entire team is stumped by this one.

We have a variable called {{adName}}, we renamed it a few weeks back to {{dlv adName}}, among 9 other variables.

The other 9 variables are okay, but we keep getting this one error -

> Unknown variable 'dlv adName' found in a tag. Edit the tag and remove the reference to the unknown variable.

When we remove it, the tag works fine, but we need the adName and it's not letting us use it. We've checked the spelling, special characters, tried manually typing in the code and nothing appears to let us use this variable.

Comment: I don't know if you've already tried this, but you could create an alternate variable that fulfills the exact same function, and replace it.

Comment: Check your whitespace (leading and trailing ws is trimmed in variable names, but not in the middle). I tend to avoid WS in my naming conventions since sometimes the accidental double space is easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing the whitespaces around my variable name in the curly brackets:

From: {{ myVariableName }}

To: {{myVariableName}}

and then it worked. Make sure you don't have any whitespaces.